# Not able to pair Raspberry Pi3 and iBeacon using Bluetooth

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth

In my current project, I am working with iBeacon in the area of IoT. Basically iBeacon works on Bluetooth wireless technology. I am using Raspberry Pi 3 (with in-built WiFi and Bluetooth).

Pi 3 Bluetooth display and detect the iBeacon but not able to do pairing with it and display the following error:

```
GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed
```

I also tried with `bluetoothctl` command also but again display the 
`Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed`
 error.

Am I missing something? I am able to pair iBeacon with my mobile and windows based laptop.

Comment: As I know, iBeacon is not needed to be paired. It sends advertising packets that contains all needed info. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Michael: But as per my knowledge pairing should be done. Please feel free to correct me.

Comment: @Michael I was just writing the same comment because iBeacon don't need pairing. Is there another reason for pairing? Please elaborate.

Comment: @MatsK- I will move forward without pairing and let you know.

Comment: "*I will move forward without pairing and let you know.*" - Still working on this? Or have you solved your problem? Then please make an answer and accept it after two days. Only accepting an answer will finish the quesiton and it will not popup again and again for years.

Answer (score 0):

iBeacon is like a lighthouse that send out beacons that an application can pick up and process.

Here is a pretty good "Getting Started with iBeacon".

https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/Getting-Started-with-iBeacon.pdf